# Data structure for a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Suppose you are given a symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and consider the computation of the matrix vector product $A u \rightarrow v$ where $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is given and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is computed.
>
> a.) Since the matrix is symmetric, there are only $n(n+1)/2$ elements that are free to choose while the others are set due to symmetry. Describe a data structure that would only store $n(n+1)/2$ values that specify $A$.

Attempted solution - Notice that for any $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, the elements $a_{1n}$ and $a_{n1}$ of $A$ will be equal. Therefore, we only need to store $1$ of these elements and we can set $a_{1n} = a_{n1}$ and thus only store $n(n+1)/2$ elements. For example, consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1\\ 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$ clearly $A$ is a symmetric matrix and so we can store this matrix in an $n$ by $n$ array and set $a_{12} = a_{21}$ and thus we store $n(n+1)/2 \ \rightarrow \ 2(2+1)/2 = 3$ values that specify $A$. Moreover, we just need to store the lower tridiagonal part of $A$.

> b.) Describe an algorithm using pseudo-code that uses your data structure to implement the computation of $Au\rightarrow v$ given $A$ and $u$. Make sure you point out all of the relevant features that influence efficiency.

Attempted solution - Now we want to compute $Au\rightarrow v$ given $A$ and $u$. We described in the latter above that we can store $n(n+1)/2$ entries of $A$ in an $n$ by $n$ array. Notice that since we set $a_{1n} = a_{n1}$ we only need to store the lower tridiagonal matrix of $A$. Thus store these elements $a_{ij}$ for $i \geq j$ in a $2$-dimensional array $L(i,j)$. The vectors $u$ and $v$ are stored in the $1$-dimensional arrays $U$ and $V$.

Now that I defined the necessary information I am struggling with writing the psuedo-code to perform the computation. Any suggestion or in the abovsolutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be more suitable for the programming SE forum.

Comment: @Travis ok, is it called programming SE? Should I delete this question and post there?

Comment: I recommend migrating this question is to the computational science forum, i.e. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you think of $A$ as $A = L + D + L^T$ where $D$ is diagonal and $L$ is strictly lower triangular. You are storing $L$ and $D$, but not $L^T$ because it is redundant. To compute $Ax$ you simply need to sum $Lx, Dx$, and $L^Tx$.

In general, you want to access memory in a monotone manner and reuse data as much as possible before it is evicted from the L1 cache. Let $l_j$ denote the $j$th column of $L$. If $L$ is stored by columns, then the sum
$$ Lx = \sum_{j=1}^n l_j x_j $$
will give you $Lx$ using stride one access of $L$ and $x$. Similarly
$$ (L^T x )_i = l_i^T x $$
will allow you to access the columns of $L$ using stride one access. The repeated reads required for $x$ are less of a problem if you have room for both $A$ and $x$ in, say, the L1 or even the L2 cache.

Certainly, many other optimizations are possible, especially if $x$ is not just a single vector, but based on the phrasing of the exercise I think that this is enough.

Comment: I see, so was my answer to part (a) good enough? I believe it makes sense and shows that I only need to store $n(n+1)/2$ elements in the array.

Comment: You have the right idea. I recommend that you make a specific illustration of how the entries of an $n$ by $n$ symmetric dense matrix would be store in memory. Pick a value of $n$ which is so small that you can do it in a reasonable amount of time, yet so large that the general pattern is clear.

Comment: Does you answer also touch upon part b.) as well?